# multisearch give diffrent total hits in different runs

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `Elasticsearch` 6.8 and `python` 3.

I'm running on my laptop with 1 node, and there are no threads/processes that insert/update/delete docs into the index while I'm running the multi search

I'm running the following multi search command:

```
    es = Elasticsearch()
    search_arr = []
    # search-1
    search_arr.append({'index': 'test1', 'type': 'type1'})
    search_arr.append({"query": {"term": {"confidence": "1"}}})

    # search-2
    search_arr.append({'index': 'test1', 'type': 'type1'})
    search_arr.append({"query": {"match_all": {}}, 'from': 0, 'size': 2})

    request = ''
    for each in search_arr:
        request += '%s \n' % json.dumps(each)

    res = es.msearch(body=request)
    print("First Query, num of results = ", res['responses'][0]['hits']['total'])
    print("Second Query, num of results = ", res['responses'][1]['hits']['total'])
```

Each time I run this code, I'm getting different results (as I wrote before, there are no processes that insert/delete/update documents)

Why I'm getting different result each time ?

And what I need to do in order to fix it and get consistent results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem cause.

I needed to add `refresh = True`  after the first time I added new data.

(I bulked thousands of new documents and right after use the multi search).